# Python Selenium ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I already tried several methods to click on a link on a specific website, with the help of Selenium. All of them resulting in following error message:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element [LMGP06050001](/data/LMSDRecord.php?LMID=...) is not clickable at point (159, 364). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

What am I doing wrong?

The goal is to reach following site and grab several data from there:
https://www.lipidmaps.org/data/LMSDRecord.php?LMID=LMGP06050001

Below my code so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\anaconda3\\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

browser.get("https://www.lipidmaps.org/data/structure/LMSDSearch.php?Mode=ProcessClassSearch&LMID=LMGP0605")

link = browser.find_element_by_link_text("LMGP06050001")
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason you have faced that issue because `cookie` pop up appeared and you need to accept the cookie first.

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for element_to_be_clickable()

```
browser.get("https://www.lipidmaps.org/data/structure/LMSDSearch.php?Mode=ProcessClassSearch&LMID=LMGP0605")

#Accept to cookie
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#cookie_notice_accept"))).click()

WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"LMGP06050001"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by @Kunduk is a good and valid one, I'd like to provide an alternative.

If you, for some reason, can't remove the element that is overlapping the element you want to click, you can use:

```
btn = self.driver.find_element("xpath", XPATH_BUTTON)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

This will use JavaScript to click the button instead, and it works no matter if there is an elelement overlapping it.